# Trace inequality: $\mathrm{Tr}(|\rho^{1-t}x\rho^t|)\leq \mathrm{Tr}(|\rho^{1-t}y\rho^t|)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, operator-algebras, trace

I've been researching some operator spaces and have stumbled upon the following problem. Suppose $x,y\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ (for $\mathcal{H}$ separable) such that $0\leq x\leq y\leq 1$. Further let $t\in[0,1]$ and $\rho$ be a density matrix (i.e. $\rho\geq 0$, $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho)=1$). Is it true that
$$
\mathrm{Tr}\big(\vert \rho^{1-t}x\rho^t\vert\big)\leq \mathrm{Tr}\big(\vert \rho^{1-t}y\rho^t\vert\big) \leq 1?
$$
Obviously this holds for $t=\frac{1}{2}$, but I'm not really sure how to approach it for other values. I've tried playing around with the polar decomposition but haven't gotten anywhere.

<s>I'm convinced that the inequality is actually true at least in the case of $2\times 2$ matrices as I've run a randomized computer search and have not found any counterexamples, but even there trying to prove it directly by writing out all the matrices is very ugly.</s>

EDIT: I've verified the inequality numerically on matrices of sizes up to $5\times 5$ with $10\,000$ random samples per size (hopefully the code is correct, generating random unitaries is a bit tricky).

It seems my code was indeed incorrect.

Comment: Why is it obvious that this holds for $t = 1/2$?

Comment: Since $x$ is positive, $\rho^{1/2}x\rho^{1/2}$ is still positive, so $\vert \rho^{1/2} x \rho^{1/2}\vert = \rho^{1/2} x \rho^{1/2}$. Similarly for $y$. Then just use the cyclicity of the trace and the fact that $y-x\geq 0$.

Comment: I somehow missed that $x$ and $y$ were positive, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first inequality is not true.

For a counterexample, consider $t = 1$, $\rho = v v^{*}$ for a unit vector $v$. Then one checks that $\textrm{Tr}(|x \rho|) = \|x(v)\|$, so the inequality is equivalent to $$ \langle x^{2}(v), v\rangle = \|x(v)\|^{2} \leq \|y(v)\|^{2} \leq \langle y^{2}(v), v\rangle, $$ i.e. $x^2 \leq y^{2}$. It is however not true in general that $0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1$ implies $x^2 \leq y^2$, as can be seen by considering say $x = u u^{*}$ and $y = x + \varepsilon w w^{*}$ for small enough $\varepsilon$ and $u, w \in \mathcal{H}$ not parallel or orthogonal.

The second inequality is true and follows from Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Hm... I don't know where my numerics went wrong, but I agree with your argument. I think I have an explicit 2x2 counterexample (I used your method but cleaned up the entries a bit by hand):
$$
\rho = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
x = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 4\\
4 & 2
\end{pmatrix},\quad
y = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2\\
2 & 6
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $x\leq y$ but $\mathrm{Tr}(|\rho x|) = 2\sqrt{5}$ while $\mathrm{Tr}(|\rho y|) = \sqrt{13}$.

Comment: Looks good! While I don't know about your code, in my experience it can be remarkably difficult to find counterexamples to such inequalities; especially when one is searching through bigger (> 2x2) matrices. I wrote a little checker myself and even in the 2x2 case it took over 30000 trials to find a counterexample.

Comment: Actually the $x$ I wrote above is not positive definite ($\det x = -12$)... But yeah, counterexamples do exist.